# How do I check if this date format is in the future?

Tags: php

My date is being returned like `01/05/2013 12:44`.  How do I check in php if this datetime is in the future?

Comment: Where do you get this data ? From the user ?

Comment: I cannot format it in a different way

Comment: Convert to both date to timestamp and compare

Comment: @Nicola: It didn't ask to format it. I aksed where do you get it from. E.g. if it comes from the client side, you need to apply timezone changes, beacause the client and server might be on different timezones.

Comment: ah I see, sorry about that.  No it comes from the server.

Comment: Did you search for your question? This has been answered on more than one occasion, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832467/php-how-can-i-check-if-the-current-date-time-is-past-a-set-date-time) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare time() with the UNIX timestamp representation of that date:

```
if (time() < strtotime("01/05/2013 12:44"))
{
    // your time is greater than todays date
}
```

Another way

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$date) )
if ($time > time())
{
  echo "$date is in the future."
}
```

Comment: this works thanks, I'll accept in 10 minutes when it lets me

Comment: I am trying to convert my datetime format to something like 30th May 2013 8pm, but when I do an echo of `strtotime($meetings[0]['date'])` nothing prints out.  Why is this?  I did try to format it but it was coming out with 1-1-1970 so thats why I echoed the value.  I have also tried print_r.

Comment: Its not working after all :(.  I just changed my date to the past and it was still showing it.

Comment: This second way works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$dt = '01/05/2013 12:44';
$nowdt = time();
$diff = strtotime($dt) - $nowdt;
echo $diff;
if($diff > 0){
 echo (" your date is future date");
} else {
    echo ("your date is is not future date");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php).

Example in pseudo code:

```
$today     = mktime("today");
$your_date = mktime("...");

if ($your_date > $today) {
    // it's in the future
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Unix time, then see if it's greater than the current time.

```
<?php
if(strtotime("01/05/2013 12:44") > time()) {
 //time is in the future.
}else{
  //time is in the past
}
?>
```