# If date from database is before current date

Tags: php

Basically what I'm trying to do is do an if command to check a date returned from database vs the current date (todays date or tomorrows date if i go on the page tomorrow)

I was thinking of something along the lines of

```
$date = "2013-11-10 20:28:41";   
if ($date < Curdate) 
{
    echo "expired";
}
```

if anyone can give me any insight on the correct commands for this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2832579/1438393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime(); // Now
$date = new DateTime('2013-11-10 20:28:41'); // From the DB
if ($date < $now) 
{
    echo "expired";
}
```

**Reference**: [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?

Comment: It is. I have voted to close. Any reason you haven't yet?

Comment: Why answer the question if you know it's a duplicate? (feel free to, but I was just wondering) :)

Comment: I didn't until I saw your comment. I always close when a dupe.

Comment: Thank you for this, just what i was looking for :) Nice and simply put for a newbie like myself :)

Comment: Oh and keep in mind, it may be a duplicate, but newbies like me don't really know what to search to find the commands we want, or we look at a piece of code that is done so expertly that it can be difficult to decode what we need. - I did spend an hour searching and trying things before i resorted to posting - So yeh thank you for your replys

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = new DateTime($date);
$now = new DateTime();
if ($dt < $now) {
  echo "before";
}
else {
  echo "after";
}
```

Comment: Its a great feature, and im sure ill find some use for it in the future. Never even thought to run a before and after. However with what im currently coding I only need the one command :) Thank you for your time tho