# Find the difference between current time and time value stored in the database?

Tags: php

```
$fetch=mysql_query("select * from code where user_email='$email' order by reg_date desc limit 1");
$db=mysql_fetch_array($fetch);
print_r($db);
$db_date=$db['reg_date'];
$db_time=$db['time'];
echo "DB_Date:".$db_date."--";
echo "DB_time:".$db_time."--";


        $current_date = date('Y-m-d');  
        echo "present date".$current_date."--";
        $curent_time = date('H:i:s');
        echo "current time:".$curent_time."--";
        $first_time = strtotime($curent_time);
        $last_time = strtotime($db_time);
        $time = $first_time - $last_time;

        $time_differenc= ($time/60)%60;
        echo "difference".$time_difference."--";
```

In the above code, i'm getting the present time,date and time,date value stored in the db correctly,but when i tried to find the difference between current time and time stored in the database, i cant get the difference.

When i give the time directly like strtotime('11:30:02'); the difference can be calculated but when i tried to get the time value which is stored in database, i cant!!!

Help me soon!!! I'm trying a lot....

Comment: what type of data have you stored in db

Comment: i have stored it as Varchar.

Comment: Sorry thats is not working

Comment: why can't you change db to accomodate datetime in a single field. then you can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832467/php-how-can-i-check-if-the-current-date-time-is-past-a-set-date-time

Comment: i tried it,but when i store the date and time in same field,after i fetch it and convert it using srttotime(), the difference becomes 2348900 like this in minutes...not exactly.But the difference shows like this only...thats why it tried to change it in separate fields...

Comment: so what do you want in your difference I dont get. what type of difference do you want

Comment: I want the exact difference in minutes like 20 mins.

Comment: that depends on the date and time...if your date and time is 
indb: 10-02-2014 10:20:00
current: 11-02-2014 10:20:00

then difference would 24 hours so its dependent..if its same date then you get in minutes

Comment: show me what you have saved in your db colum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you need to specifically set the timezone else by default it takes `UTC`

```
$dbdatetime = $row['datetime'];//datetime from database: "2014-05-18 18:10:18"
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); //setting default timezone based on your location
$curdatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //current datetime

if($curdatetime > $dbdatetime){
    $diff = abs(strtotime($curdatetime) - strtotime($dbdatetime));
}else{
    $diff = abs(strtotime($dbdatetime) - strtotime($curdatetime));
}
echo "The difference is "$diff/60." minutes";
```

Comment: "date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");"--->  After i have added this code,i'm getting the difference.Thank you so much !!